# For $n \geq 1$, show that $G= \{e^{2 \pi k i/n} : k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ has $n$ distinct elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-numbers

> For $n \geq 1$, show that $G= \{e^{2 \pi k i/n} : k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ has $n$ distinct elements.

The first part of the problem asked us to show that $G$ is a group.  I did that and will omit the work as it is straight forward when using the fact that $e^{z_{1}+z_{2}}=e^{z_{1}}e^{z_{2}}$, $z \in \mathbb{C}$.

The question also reminds us that $e^{2 \pi n i}=1$ for all integers $n$ and that $e^{a+bi}=e^{a}(\cos(b)+i\sin(b))$.

But I do not know how to approach proving this set has $n$ distinct elements.  Any help or hints would be much appreciated!

Comment: Which difficulty did you meet to show that these are all distinct for $0\le k\le n-1$?

Comment: I don't even know how to show that.

Comment: Well, what equations do you get concerning the real and imaginary parts if two of these numbers are equal?

Comment: Did you try to solve for $(k,\ell)$ integers the identity $$e^{2i\pi k/n}=e^{2i\pi\ell/n}\ ?$$

Comment: If these two are equal then $(\cos(2 \pi k) + i \sin(2 \pi k))^{1/n} = (\cos(2 \pi l) + i \sin(2 \pi l))^{1/n}$. So $k=0$ and $l=1$ would satisfy this.  Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: By using $e^{ix}=e^{iy}$ if and only if $x-y=2k\pi$
$$\frac{2f\pi}{n}-\frac{2l\pi}{n}=\frac{2\pi}{n}(f-l)<\frac{2\pi}{n}.n=2\pi$$ where $0\leq f,l\leq n-1$

Comment: I have never seen this proposition that you state here.  I am not seeing how this helps my problem.

Comment: $e^{ix} =e^{iy}\Rightarrow \cos x+i\sin x=\cos y+i \sin y\Rightarrow \cos x=\cos y,  \sin x=\sin y$ so $x-y=2k\pi$.

Comment: Now suppose  $G= \{e^{2 \pi k i/n} : k=0, 1, 2,.., n-1\}$, elements arenot distinct so you have for example $e^{\frac{2f\pi}{n}}$ and $e^{\frac{2l\pi}{n}} $ which are equal. ....